# Error code 105, can't get it fixed MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Allright so I know this question have been asked multiple times on Stackoverflow and anywhere on the internet. Yet I still can't seem to figure my problem out...**

First I'm creating this table:

```
create table player
    (   id_player       char(32)    not null,
        joindate        date        not null,
        name            char(32)    not null,
    primary key (id_player)
    );
```

Then after that when I try to make a second table, that references the first in a foreign key:

```
create table player_faction
    (   id_player       char(32),
        joindate        date        not null,
        rank            char(20)    not null,
        power           integer,
    foreign key (id_player) references player
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade
    );
```

It gives me a error 105 which stands for not able to reference to the first table for some reason.
I understand that but I just can't figure out why?
Is there someone who sees what I'm doing wrong, I've been hurting my head on this for the past hour or so...

It is probably a really small, stupid mistake, thanks for helping!

**Problem was solved, if you want my solution, look below, it is really stupid!**

Comment: You are missing the referenced column. You named the table, but need `(id_player)` in `()`. as in `FOREIGN KEY (id_player) REFERENCES player (id_player) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97c84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MYSQL [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). You are almost near, just missing syntax near `references`

```
create table player_faction
    (   id_player       char(32),
        joindate        date        not null,
        rank            char(20)    not null,
        power           integer,
    foreign key (id_player) references player(id_player)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade
    );
```

Comment: Whauw, I was looking at the wrong point all the time. Thanks alot for the response, this works perfect :)

Comment: I was planning to but for some reason it didn't let me yet, I think you can accept an answer like 15 minutes after posting ;)